# Constructing Clojure defmulti/defmethod

Tags: clojure

I am missing an important point about defmulti and defmethod. I've read several books' explanation of defmulti, and I'm still confused.

I want to get a random value depending on whether or not it's a transaction or an amount like 100.00

I want to call (random-val) and either get back an avail-trans value or random decimal amount. I have experimented with putting the functions in a map, but I get the same value back for avail-trans, a \B.

```
(def^:dynamic map-val {:trans (random-trans) :amt (random-amount)})
```

Here is the smallest amount of code to show what I'm doing that is not working. I'd appreciate any pointers or help.

```
(def^:dynamic avail-trans [\B \W \D \A])

(defn random-trans 
    [] 
    (nth avail-trans (.nextInt random (count avail-trans))))

(defn random-amount
    []
    (float (/ (.nextInt random (count (range 1 10000))) 25 )))
```

The following is not constructed correctly, but I'm not sure why or how to fix the problem:

```
(defmulti random-val :val-type)

(defmethod random-val :trans []
    (random-trans))

(defmethod random-val :amt []
    (random-amount))
```

Calling `(random-val :trans)` results in this error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method in multimethod 'random-val' for dispatch value: null (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A multimethod is created with `defmulti`; you're doing that right. `defmulti` needs a name and a dispatch function (and a docstring, plus some options, if you desire, but forget about those).

```
(defmulti random-val identity)
```

When you implement the multimethod with `defmethod`, you need to specify the name of the multimethod you're implementing, the dispatch value it should match, and then the function tail (arglist plus whatever you want it to do).

```
(defmethod random-val :trans [t] (random-trans))
(defmethod random-val :amt [t] (random-amt))
```

You're getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method in multimethod 'random-val' for dispatch value: null (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)` because when the dispatch function you assigned `random-val`, `:val-type` is applied to any other keyword, it gives you `null`. When Clojure tries to look up a method to match that dispatch value, it fails.

But even if it didn't fail there, your defined methods have 0 arity (take no values), so you need to fix that, too (done above).

Finally, this doesn't seem like a good use for protocols. Just use your two separate function, `random-amount` and `random-trans`.

Note, too, that [Clojure's website](http://clojure.org/multimethods) has a good explanations of multimethods.

Comment: I appreciate the answer very much. The two answers (so far) here are better than what I've seen out on Clojure's web site. No wise-guy intended, but Clojure seems to me to be one of those "It takes a village" languages/learning experiences. I get something from listening to all answers.

Comment: You've convinced me not to use this particular example for multimethods, but to experiment, if I re-arranged my example as you have shown, how would I call it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking; you mean, how would you do it if you wanted to use multimethods? The code I wrote above should work as you intended.

Answer (score 2):

You get the same value back every time for avail-trans '`\B`' because you are evaluating the function when you associate it in your map `map-val`, thus binding the value `B` forever against the key ':trans' in map-val, instead of the function `randon-trans` itself.

If you remove the parens around your function assignments in map-val, it will work just fine. Then there is no need for multimethods, which are probably not appropriate as @isaac-hodes suggests.

This works for me in the REPL:

```
(def avail-trans [\B \W \D \A])
(def random (java.util.Random.))

(defn random-trans []
  (nth avail-trans (.nextInt random (count avail-trans))))

(defn random-amount []
  (float (/ (.nextInt random (count (range 1 10000))) 25 )))

; No parens around function names
(def map-val {:trans random-trans :amt random-amount})

(println ((:trans map-val)))
(println ((:amt map-val)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I was trying to peace out what was going wrong in the repl.